# Network Adapter Unclaimed - RTL8822CE 802.11ac

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, 23.04

I dual booted my computer from Windows 11 along with Ubuntu 23.04.

The WiFi was working great, but after reboot, it stopped working.

I checked the WiFi adapter using `sudo lshw -C network`
It shows that the adapter is Unclaimed.

I tried to find a driver for the same, but I found that the adapter is only for Windows 10. But it was working some time ago.

I had the same issue when I first installed Pop OS.
I had dual booted this system with Ubuntu in the past too, but did not face this issue back then.

Output of `sudo lshw -C network`:
[image]